# Run javascript code on Form Submit

Tags: javascript, forms

I want to run JavaScript code upon a form being submitted preceding other default tasks that are carried out on form submission.

May anyone suggest some approaches?

Comment: What type of JavaScript code do you need to run before the form handlers are invoked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the type of code that you need to run, and from the Drupal version, AHAH and AJAX could be the answer.

On Drupal API, there is example code for [AHAH](http://api.drupal.org/api/examples/ahah_example--ahah_example.module/group/ahah_example/6) (Drupal 6), and [AJAX](http://api.drupal.org/api/examples/ajax_example--ajax_example.module/group/ajax_examples/7) (Drupal 7 and higher).